# Job schedulars - web sphere application server 8.5/Liberty profile

Tags: spring, websphere, quartz-scheduler, websphere-liberty, job-scheduling

we have WebSphere application server 8.5 environment, having different applications deployed into different instances. And we have requirement that needing job/process scheduler to be picked up by any one of instances(only one), if any instance goes down, failover should happen(which environment will take care) and how to achieve using spring or quartz or any other mechanism.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This capability is built in to traditional WebSphere Application Server via Persistent EJB Timers and the Scheduler service, which are configurable across a cluster.  However, Liberty does not have a built-in failover capability for scheduled tasks.  You can vote for a Request for Enhancement for this capability here,

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=101976

Comment: can we write custom generic persistent timers without EJB concept as we are using spring only.

Comment: Certainly, I'm just pointing out there is no built-in support (with EJBs or without) and have offered a link where you can vote for built-in support to be added.  You are of course free to build your own solution.